# Branching a project

Tags: git

I am pretty new to Git and would like to know if Git is the appropriate application for the following.  I have a project folder that contains python code that I have saved to Git that is split into a number of code modules (all in the same folder).

```
Module 1. > Data retrieval
Module 2. > Data cleaning
Module 3. > Rules based processing
Module 4. > Output
```

I would like to create several different projects based on this original project that are the same as the original project but have different Module 3's (different rule sets for processing the data) but use the same modules before and after as the original project.  So I can offer 3 or more different ways to process the data but are output to the same output folder.

Currently it looks like I could create two new project where I copy all of the code into the new project folders and save this to Git as separate projects but seeing as a lot of the modules will be the same as the original project can I was wondering if I can create branches and change the code in module 3 in each branch to to be different without interfering with the original code (I don't want to touch the original project)?

So I would have

```
Original                            Branch 1                                     Branch 2
Module 1. > Data retrieval          Module 1. > Data retrieval                   Module 1. > Data retrieval
Module 2. > Data cleaning           Module 2. > Data cleaning                    Module 2. > Data cleaning 
Module 3. > Rules based processing  Module 3.1. > New Rules based processing 3.1 Module 3.2. > New Rules based processing 3.2 
Module 4. > Output                  Module 4. > Output                           Module 4. > Output
```

Basically I don't want to lose my original code and I want to be as efficient as possible creating the additional separate functionality.

Comment: In principle you could, but the question is whether that is the best approach. Keep in mind that with branches, an update to say `main` for Module 1 will not be updated in a `module3.1` branch until you merge any new commits. You did not describe what language you are using here so I don't know how different Module 3 is vs 3.1. If the issue is activation this could be done in some scripting with some keyword flags, etc.

Comment: Thanks @astrochun the modules are coded in Python.  Would merging mean that I would loose the original project - I would like to keep the three modules separate - maybe it would be better to just create 2 new module 3's and switch between them?

Comment: I think, based on what I'm hearing, it's not difficult to code when to use module3.py vs module3_1.py. That is you most likely don't need branches. The pain with using branches is that if you are doing a full pipeline where you run module1, module2, module3/module3_1, and module4, you will need to switch branch in the middle and then switch back.